# Crop pdf document into multiple pdfs based on font size with python

Tags: python, pdf

I want to split PDF document based on the font size, but I am not able to find the library which will do both extract the font size and split.

https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber can extract the information such as font size, location of the character.

pyPdf can split the PDF document and can save in another pdf if the co-ordinates are provided, but no mechanism to extract font size and other features.

I tried using them together but the location of the characters given by pdfplumber is different from the co-ordinates used by pyPdf. That is why I am getting unexpected output.

Is there any library in python which will do both? or is there any way I can use location provided by pdfplumber in pypdf?

Comment: Have you looked at PDFMiner? https://github.com/euske/pdfminer This lets you parse and convert. Not totally sure if this would help you split, but I expect it does.

Comment: i couldn't find any tool to split document in pdfminer. I think pdfminer only converts pdf into html,txt,doc. correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: This suggests you can: https://youtu.be/BhgE6d7zhYQ doesn’t it?

Comment: How do the coordinates from PDFPlumber differ from those in PyPDF? Is it possible one starts in the upper-left of the page and the other in the lower-left of the page so you can convert between them?

Comment: yes found the solution , while working with pypdf the origin is at left bottom of the page. Thanks , I am able to use pypdf with co-ordinates provided by pdfplumber.

Comment: Could you put the solution here? Thanks @SuyogChadawar

Comment: You can combine pdfminer.six with `pypdf`. First get the pages with pdfminer and then crop with pypdf